# Высылка переменных из Javascript на e-mail

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cross-domain

Есть у меня html страница с формами input. 
С помощью JS у меня генерируются некоторые переменные. 
А так же есть input, values которых я НЕ генерирую (имя, email)
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы данные отправлялись на мой e-mail. И данные смешанные - переменные со скрипта, а так же values из input.

Пока что дошел до такого

Нашел в интернете функцию которую переделал

```js
function sendemaildata() {
  $bigvolume = $('#big-volume').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    file: "e-mail-form/send-form.php",
    data: $bigvolume,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Сообщение отправлено");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".feedback_form_bg").fadeOut();
      }, 1000);
    },
    error: function(xhr, str) {
      alert("Возникла ошибка!");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".feedback_form_bg").fadeOut();
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
}
```

После этого скопировал php код для отправки e-mail

```php
$bigvolume = $_POST[$bigvolume];
$customeremail = $_POST['email'];
$emailTo = 'мойимейл@gmail.com';
$body = $country$loadcountry "$fio \n\n$phone\n\n$email \n\n$adres";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
  'From: MySite <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 
  'Reply-To: ' . $emailTo;
mail($emailTo, $fio, $body, $headers);
$emailSent = true;
```

И еще добавил функцию чтобы функция `sendemaildata` выполнялась после нажатия кнопки

```js
document.getElementById("send-price-to-us").onclick = sendemaildata;
```

Так вот, при нажатии кнопки с `#send-price-to-us` у меня появляется ошибка.

> Failed to load file:///D:/.........../index.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Кроме того выскакивает алерт

```js
alert("Возникла ошибка!");
```

Как мне сделать чтобы запрос нормально высылался. И смогу ли я вставлять переменные из предыдущих функций? Будут ли они работать?

Comment: Куда скопировали php код? Судя по `file:///D:/.........../index.html`, вы пытаетесь отправить форму в html файл. Для работы php на локальной машине нужно поднять локальный сервер

Comment: Высылка переменных под негласный надзор.

Comment: У меня включен локальный сервер. Страница с формой и скриптом на html но файл для почты называется send-form.php и он ан php написан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемма решилась благодаря отправке файла на локальный сервер. Спасибо за ответы. Если у кого будут вопросы то задавайте.